# Is this graph possible to do using Highchart?

Tags: javascript, django, highcharts

I am using Django chartit which utilizes Highcharts API. Is this graph possible to make?
[image]

Comment: Yes, it's possible. I see only one thing not supported in Highcharts, it's second xAxis with separators (`25Feb2015 | 26Feb2015 | ... `). However, it should be possible to achieve such labels by using another xAxis with different `tickInterval` or `tickPositioner`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can draw it in Highcharts, this is a problem of multiple axes.

Here is the demo page in Highcharts.com: http://www.highcharts.com/demo/combo-multi-axes